# Issue with Elasticsearch sort

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

We have 3 sorting options in our application:
Recommended, Distance and Rating.
User can search by a Service and/or a Location. By default, if location is filled we show results that are within 50 miles of the search location. if service is filled, we show all professionals that provide that service.
When both are selected we query all professional within 50 miles of the location that provide that service.

Now the problem:
I want to show the results from query above, assign weightage to one of the parameters(recommended, distance, rating)
Eg:
Recommended sort: 50% weightage Recommended, 30% rating, 20% distance
Distance sort: 70% weightage distance, 20% recommended, 10% rating
Rating sort: 70% rating, 20% distance, 10% recommended

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have tried boost, and score. The wrokaround we have on the sie is making multiple queries and showing the top 5 queries as recommended, next 10 with 2nd parameter and remaining with 3rd. We pop displayed results from previous query in the subsequent query.